# Interval for all Http requests (Using retrofit and Rx Java 2)

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm trying to create an app for remote control of the robot (anyway, it doesn't matter), and I faced with a problem, that server-side (on the robot) is so weak to process all http requests from smartphone. But still I can send one request per 100-150 ms. I'm using Rx Java and retrofit to send all requests; 
What I'm trying to ask is Can I schedule **ALL** the requests and send them with a constant interval? 
I have basePresenter in my app, which is send 'any' request to server and check whether is connected or not(and doing it with some interval itself):

```
requestInterface.checkConnectionToRobot()
                .doOnError(err -> {err.printStackTrace(); action(false);})
                .retryWhen(o -> o.delay(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .repeatWhen(o -> o.delay(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(next -> action(true))
                .subscribe(new DisposingObserver<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(final Disposable d) {
                        addContinuous(d);
                    }
                });
```

As you could understand, this check has to repeat infinetely. The problem occurs, when I'm trying to make one more request like that (for example for checking some information from robot sensors etc.):

```
requestInterface.refreshBaseData()
                .retryWhen(o -> o.delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .repeatWhen(o -> o.delay(refreshRate, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(RefreshDataConverter::convertData)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(next -> getViewState().setBaseData(next))
                .subscribe(new DisposingObserver<RefreshData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(final Disposable d) {
                        addContinuous(d);
                        baseCheckDisposable = d;
                    }
                });
```

Request is almost the same, and it is delaying itself. 
But when they work both, they can overlap themselves, and server can crush.
I've tried `Observable.interval` and `Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())`

Like this one:

```
scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(n ->
                        requestInterface.checkConnectionToRobot()
                                .subscribeOn(scheduler))
                .doOnError(err -> {err.printStackTrace(); action(false);})
                .retryWhen(o -> o.delay(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .repeatWhen(o -> o.delay(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(next -> action(true))
                .subscribe(new DisposingObserver<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(final Disposable d) {
                        addContinuous(d);
                    }
                });
```

The same on another request, but still they are overlapping each other.
What am I doing wrong? I just need to send all requests from my app with delay(maybe I need some kind of manager or what?). 
P.S. any corrections of my code are welcome.:)
Thanks